# Print Formatted Text to a Serial Port

Tags: c#, serial-port, printers

I am trying to write a content to the serial port which will be communicated to a printer using bluetooth. I am using .NET CF 3.5 - Windows Mobile 6.5 and Citizen Printer PD 24.

I am able to write the text to the printer but the problem is that i want to format it like Bold Characters, Increase the Font size and others options. I don't know how to do that.

Any Suggestions?
Write now i am using this following Code:

```
 string printString = "APPLICATION FORM  \b0 \r\n";
 printString += "Name of First Applicant: " + ApplicantTitle + "." + ApplicantName + "\n";
 port.Write(printString);
 port.Close();
```

Thanks for reading the post

Regards
Biju

Comment: Thanks Martin for this edit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the programming manual for the printer to know what control codes to send.  You can download [it here](http://www.citizen-europe.com/pdf/pd24cmrf.pdf).

Comment: Hi Hans, I saw those commands but how do i use them in my C# code? any idea on how to use it?

Comment: Hi Hans, \n I found the way to use those commands ` Printsting += "\xb1k3 Name"; ` \n Thanks for the help again